# How to extract the line numbers from a file containing backslash

Tags: python

I have a file which contains many backslash()
I want to know the line numbers of a file containing \
Is there any way in python to find out line numbers containing \

Regards
Nagendra

Comment: I'd read the file into a list, then iterate through the list, saving the index if there's a slash in the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape/backslash that backslash with a backslash. xD

```
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    print([i for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()) if "\\" in line])
```